# Display name in rails should contain first name and initial of last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a students collection result set and I need following.
Display names should be resolved following these rules: If there are no other students in the collection with the same first name, their display
name should be just their first name.

2. If there are multiple students in the collection with the same first name, their display name should be their first name followed by a space and their last initial(e.g. “John Smith” would resolve to “John S”)..

Comment: Is your result set an active record objects array, or you want to do it in a Hash?

Comment: yes it is an active record relation result set

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@results.each do |object|
  displayname = (@results.select { |filter_object| filter_object.first_name == object.first_name }.count > 0) ? object.first_name : object.first_name + " " + object.last_name.initial
end
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example, this might not specifically be what you need (this kinda sounds like homework), but hopefully it gives you an idea.

```
# in Student model
attr_accessor :display_name

# in controller
students = Student.all
students.each do |student|
  if students.count { |s| s.first_name == student.first_name } > 1
    student.display_name =  s.first_name
  else
    student.display_name = "#{student.first_name} #{student.last_name[0].upcase}"
  end
end

# in view
<% students.each do |student| %>
  <%= student.display_name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out duplicate first names.

```
dup_first_names = Student.select(:first_name).group(:first_name).group(:first_name).having("COUNT(*) > 1").uniq.pluck(:first_name)
```

Then for each student check whether the first name is in the `dup_first_names` array.

```
Student.all.each do |s|
  if dup_first_names.include?(s.first_name)
    puts "#{s.first_name} #{s.last_name.first}" 
  else
    puts "#{s.first_name}" 
  end
end
```